# python pandas: how to use concat() to do a SQL union?

Tags: python, pandas, union, concatenation

I understand from the documentation that I can use `concat()` to do the equivalent of a SQL UNION.

However, this only seems to work when the columns have the same name. What can I do when the columns have different names?

Let's say I have a table with 3 fields: id, value1, value2 and I want a new table with 2 columns, where id is repeated, and value2 is appended below value1.

In SQL I'd do:

```
select id, value1 from df
UNION
select id, value2 from df
```

and value1 and value2 would end up in the same column even if they have different names. If I try this in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['id']=np.arange(0,10)
df['value1']=np.arange(100,110)
df['value2']=np.arange(300,310)

dfnew = pd.concat( [ df[['id','value1']], df[['id','value2']] ])
```

I end up with a dataframe with 3, not 2 columns.

One solution would be to manually rename the columns. This works and gives me the result I want:

```
dfnew = pd.concat( [ df[['id','value1']], df[['id','value2']].rename(columns={'value2':'value1'}) ])
```

but it seems very convoluted to me.

Any better ideas? Thanks

Comment: I think you have to do it this way, pandas will try to use existing indices and column labels for alignment without renaming you can't infer how the values should align without renaming

Answer (score 1):

You could try the melt function

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id'])[['id', 'value']]
```